# iOS9: HealthKit issue with requestAuthorizationToShareTypes

Tags: ios9, healthkit

As per the below Apple's code from Fit app, if `success` is `NO` then we determine that user have cont given access to the app to read or write data, but this approach has changed in iOS9, in iOS9 we have "**Dont Allow**" and "**Allow**" buttons, and whatever choice user makes, it returns `success` as `YES` and that mean we no longer be able to determine whether user allowed or not.

In my app I want to show the user the **steps** to activate Health kit, I was depending on this `success` flag and in iOS9 it failed. As per Apple doc (quoted below) they say that if there is no permission it will appear as if there is no data for the requested type, now I cant determine whether its because there was no data or it was because user has not given access.

Also please find Apple's dev link on it
[Developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16484)

Want to know if there is a correct approach for this.

One workaround in my mind is to check if there is a valid source just after the call back, for me I am looking for device as the source and if it is not available I assume it is an auth issue, I am putting that code also here, I might use it if dont find any other option

> To help prevent possible leaks of sensitive health information, your
>   app cannot determine whether a user has granted permission to read
>   data. If you are not given permission, **it simply appears as if there
>   is no data of the requested type in the HealthKit store.** If your app
>   is given share permission but not read permission, you see only the
>   data that your app has written to the store. Data from other sources
>   remains hidden.

**Code from Fit App**

```
if ([HKHealthStore isHealthDataAvailable]) {
    NSSet *writeDataTypes = [self dataTypesToWrite];
    NSSet *readDataTypes = [self dataTypesToRead];

    [self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:writeDataTypes readTypes:readDataTypes completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully when a user decides not to provide access. The error was: %@. If you're using a simulator, try it on a device.", error);

            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the user interface based on the current user's health information.
            [self updateUsersAgeLabel];
            [self updateUsersHeightLabel];
            [self updateUsersWeightLabel];
        });
    }];
}
```

**SOURCE DETECTION**

```
- (void)getStepSourceWithCompletion:(CompletionHandler)completion {
  NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
  HKSampleType *sampleType = [HKSampleType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];
  HKSourceQuery *sourceQuery = [[HKSourceQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:sampleType
    samplePredicate:nil
    completionHandler:^(HKSourceQuery * _Nonnull query, NSSet<HKSource *> * _Nullable sources, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
      return completion(nil, error);
    }

    if (sources && sources.count > 0) {
      for (HKSource *source in sources) {
        // Check if device is a source.
        if ([source.name isEqual:deviceName]) {
          return completion(source, nil);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [userInfo setValue:@"No suitable sources were found" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
    NSError *noSource = [NSError errorWithDomain:domain code:ErrorCodeNoSource userInfo:userInfo];
    completion(nil, noSource);
  }];

  [self.healthStore executeQuery:sourceQuery];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `success` value in the authorization callback has never indicated whether the user allowed or denied your app authorization. Prior to iOS 9, `success` would be NO if the user cancelled the authorization sheet, which just meant that the user declined to make a decision. Starting in iOS 9, however, the user has no way to delay the deciding whether to authorize your app.

You should not try to work around this lack of information. HealthKit is intentionally protecting the user's privacy.

Comment: hello, I will explain it clearly what I am trying to do. If user has not given authorization and try to refresh the screen, no steps will be found and at that point of time I want to inform the user to turn on Health access by showing the steps to do it rather than showing no steps available.

Comment: I understand that, but HealthKit is specifically designed to make it difficult to determine what you are trying to determine. You should not try to work around that.

Comment: Ok so, if we don't get any data...we should show data un-available?